# Beginner c# trouble

Tags: c#

Im new to c# and Im having a little problem. I want to make an easy program to ask the user for a integer number between 1-50, and then to display on the console if its a odd number or not. So, what i tried is this:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Skriv ut ett heltal: ");
 int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

 if (x == 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("The number is odd");
 }
 else 
 {
     Console.WriteLine("The number is not odd");
 }
```

Now i get an error at my if statements condition. How can i fix this?

Comment: What led you to believe that C# included that syntax?

Answer (score 11):

C# does not allow you specify multiple values to check a variable against using a single `if` statement.  You would need to check each value (1, 3, 5, etc) individually if you wanted to do it this way, and that would be a lot of redundant typing.

In this particular example, an easier way to check if something is odd or even is to check the remainder after dividing by 2, using the modulus operator `%`:

```
if (x % 2 == 1)
{
   Console.WriteLine("The number is odd");
}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("The number is even");
}
```

However, if you really do need to check against a list, then the easy way is to use the `Contains` method on an array (an `ICollection<T>`, really).  To make it nice and easy, you could even write an extension function that lets you check against a list in a syntactically pretty fashion:

```
public static class ExtensionFunctions
{
    public static bool In<T>(this T v, params T[] vals)
    {
        return vals.Contains(v);
    }
}
```

Then you could say:

```
if (x.In(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("The number is definitely odd and in range 1..19");
}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("The number is even, or is not in the range 1..19");
}
```

Voila!  :)

Comment: Isn't it if `x % 2 == 0` ?

Comment: @Pacane: it depends on the context - you could say either x%2==0 then it's even, or x%2==1 then it's odd.

Comment: Right, didn't see the body of the if.

Comment: Love the "In" extension method!  Btw, I fixed the output text in your example.

Comment: Yup I noticed your edit - thanks...  I think the previous text was a holdover from a previous edit that I forgot to correct.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(x % 2 == 0)
{
// It's even
}
else
{
// It's odd
}
```

Comment: It's useful to show the poster the correct way to solve this problem, you really should also point out why their current code is giving them a compiler error. They're bound to want to multiple conditionals at some point in the future, and that really is what they're asking here

Answer (score 4):

If you want to test whether x is a number in a particular list:

```
int[] list = new int[]{ 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19};
if(list.Contains(x))
```

The common way to check to see if an integer is odd is to check if it divides evenly by 2:

```
if(x % 2 == 1)
```

Comment: `x%2` would be 0 if it divided evenly.

Comment: @DanielMann Yes...and 1 if it doesn't divide evenly i.e. is odd...i.e. what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`x == 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19` is not valid syntax for expressing multiple options. If you really want to do this then you can use a `switch` statement:

```
 switch(x) {
     case 1:
     case 3:
     case 5:
     case 7:
     case 9:
     case 11:
     case 13:
     case 15:
     case 17:
     case 19:
          // is odd
          break;
     default:
          // is even
          break;
 }
```

The *correct* way would be to use the modulo operator `%` to determine if a number is exactly divisible by 2 or not, rather than trying every odd number, like so:

```
if( x % 2 == 0 ) {
   // even number
}  else {
   // odd number
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid C#. You can't test set inclusion like that. In any case, it's not practical to test for all the numbers in the world.

Why don't you just do this instead;

```
if (x &1 == 1) // mask the 1 bit
```

Bitwise operations are pretty quick so that code should be pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

While, as others have pointed out, this is not the best way to solve this problem, the reason you're getting an error in this case is because you can't have multiple values like that in an if statement. You have to word it like this:

```
if (x == 1 || x == 3 || x == 5)
```

If you don't know, `||` is the symbol for 'or'

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement should be like this if you are having multiple conditions:

if any 1 of conditions is true:

```
if(x == 1 || x == 3 || x == 5) 
{
    //it is true
}
```

if all of the condition must be true:

```
if(x == 1 && y == 3 && z == 5) 
{
    //it is true
}
```

But if you are only looking for odd/even numbers. Use the `%` operator as the other answer says.

Comment: @MichaelBray ohh.. sorry about that.. i just copied the first block code.haha. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("Skriv ut ett heltal: ");
int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine(x % 2 == 1 ? "The number is odd" : "The number is not odd");
```

x % 2 == 1 does a modulus of 2 on the input (takes as many '2's off as possible until the number is between 0 and 2 - so 0 or 1 in this case)

Comment: `%` is not a factorial - it's a modulus

Comment: Yep, you're right. It's far too late to expect my brain to function. Thanks for spotting my faux pas

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is:

```
if (x == 1 || 3 || 5){ 
Console.writeLine("oddetall");
}
```

or so it is possible to create an Array []

```
int[] odd = new int[3]; // how many odd to be tested
if(x=odd){
Console.WriteLine("Oddetall");
}
```

Comment: No. You cannot use the `||` operator on an `int`. If you changed it to `|` then you would be performing a *bitwise* or of 1, 3, and 5 (i.e. 001b | 011b | 101b == 111b == 7). I think you mean `if (x == 1 || x == 3 || x == 5)`, which would work as you want.

Comment: Likewise, you cannot use `if(x=odd)` for three reasons: **(1)** - `x` is an `int` so cannot be directly compared to an `int[]` (an array). You'd need something like `if ( odd.Contains(x) )` instead. **(2)** - you would need to use the `==` operator to compare. The `=` operator *assigns* the operand on the right to the operand on the left, which is illegal here since there is an `int[]` on the right and an `int` on the left. **(3)** - you've not actually *assigned* anything to `odd`, so it is an array of zeros. You need something like `int[] odd = new int[3] { 1, 3, 5 };` to actually assign it.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for this answer is to have some validation for user input, such as using the int.TryParse() method, to check if the value entered by the user is indeed an integer and do something else instead of crashing your program.

Code:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer between 1 and 50: ");
        bool validInteger = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int x);
        
        /*The int.TryParse() method will return a boolean value of true if                             
        the user input is an integer, as well as store the valid 
        integer as an int variable named x. Otherwise it will return 
        false if the user enters anything other than an int value.*/

        if (validInt)
        {
            /* The modulo operator (%, also called the remainder operator)
            checks if there is a remainder after dividing the value by 2 */
            if (x % 2 == 0) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number is even");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number is odd");
            }
        }
        else 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid integer only!! "); 
        }
```

Another way to write this would be to run the code inside a while loop that continues to prompt the user to enter a value if the input is not an integer.

Code:

```
        bool validInteger;

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer between 1 and 50: ");
            validInteger = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var y);

            if (validInteger)
            {
                if (y % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The number is even");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The number is odd");
                }
                /* The break statement will exit the loop once the program 
                receives a valid input */
                break;
            }
          else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid integer");
            }
        }
```

This method will continue to prompt the user for input until it receives a valid integer. Even though using nested if statements is generally not ideal and can slow down compilation time for larger applications, for a basic task like this it is perfectly acceptable.